# RxJava : How to handle the exception generated in sequence of multiple calls using flatMap operator?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I am trying to implement the following code where mulitple calls are made in sequence using flatmap operator. The `private Observable<Context> getObservable1(Context context)` is throwing an exception and the flow is supposed to stop the further execution and return with the exception which will then be handled in the `accept()` method and the response is returned back to the caller of the function.

Any pointers on how to achieve the same will be appreciated?

```
public class UserLoad {  
    public void accept(){
         Observable.just(context)
         .flatMap(context -> validationBA.execute(context)
         .flatMap(context->{
            if(isPresent(context)){
                Observable<Context> observableB = getObservableB(context);
                        return observableB;
            }else{
                Observable<Context> observableA = getObservableA(context);
                        return observableA;
            }
         })
         .subscribe((onNext) -> {
                    //handle success here
                }, (onError) -> {
                    //handle error here [expect to handle the error here and not execute other calls in the sequence]
         });
    }

    private Observable<Context> getObservableB(Context context) {
        return Observable.just(context)
                .flatMap(this::getObservable1)
                .flatMap(this::getObservable2)
                .flatMap(this::getObservable3)
                .flatMap(ClassB::execute);
    }

    private Observable<Context> getObservableA(Context context) {
        return Observable.just(context)
                .flatMap(this::getObservable1)
                .flatMap(this::getObservable2)
                .flatMap(this::getObservable3)
                .flatMap(ClassA::execute);
    }

    private Observable<Context> getObservable1(Context context) {
        return UserService.execute(context)
            .map(response -> {
                if(null==response){ 
                    throw new UserException;
                }
                return response;
            });     
    }

    private Observable<Context> getObservable2(Context context) {//some implementation}

    private Observable<Context> getObservable3(Context context) {//some implementation}
}
```

Comment: That code should already work as you described, shouldn't it?

Comment: "handled in the accept() method" <- this requires blocking which is not recommended. You should keep composing and let the caller of the API subscribe at some point. Assuming the platform is Android, you'd want to go back to the main thread with the results which won't work nicely if `accept` is blocking.